# how to advance into higher level functional programming

Tags: functional-programming

first my apologies if this isn't the right place for this question but I think that th.CS is not the right place for sure neither is StackOverflow.

I really like functional programming and I think I'm a medium level guy in F# and understand the basic concepts of Haskell rather well - and yes I think I know/fell like I know what a Monad is.

Now I really want to take this to the next level and want to understand what all the talk about functors and stuff is all about.
I just don't know where to start.

Read something about Lambda Calculus? Category Theory? Both I know a bit and I don't think that this is the right/quickest way to enlightment.

Maybe you can give me some hints on that.

PS: I'm not afraid of math and I don't get frustrated on excercises easily but I would prefere some intros/text where you can put some code down because this way you get the feedback at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Read the [Lambda Papers](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Lambda_Papers),
- Lurk around [Lamba the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/),
- Pick up a functional language (purely functional or not), like:

  - [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/),
  - [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29),
  - [OCaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml).

F# is good start, you should keep going with Haskell, and definitely read up on lambda calculus and read the [Lambda Papers](http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html) mentioned above.

Using an hybrid language (Clojure, Scala, OCaml, ...) might help to ease it onto if you come from an OO background, but I think that if you really want to understand the functional progamming mindset, you should rather go for the real thing (Haskell, Lisp, ...).

Comment: thanks - of course I will stick to F# (I can use this in production code...) and I will try to learn more haskell - but this is harder because I find it rather hard to do other things than console-applications in haskell (yet). - Scheme might be nice (had a short episode in Lisp once) but OCaml is almost the same as F# (I think)

Comment: @CarstenKönig: There are quite a lot of very interesting projects you can do without worrying about a UI. A great option is working on a programming language: writing a simple Scheme or Prolog interpreter in Haskell is an awesome exercise and lives happily on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you read those three books if time is a luxury you have:

- [Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521513383)
- [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521663504)
- [Type Theory and Functional Programming](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/)

Those three books will enrich your understanding of Functional Programming in general.

Comment: ATM time is not an issue - and I will take me some time if I find the energy on evenings anyway ... it might be slow but normaly I am able to read alot. Of course with those kinds of books I my pace will slow to a crawl ... thanks (sadly the last one seems to be out of print ... can't stand reading from screen)

Answer (score 2):

[Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) has an excellent [introduction to functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

For the really heavy stuff you can read [Oleg Kiselyov's excellent site](http://okmij.org/ftp/): delimited continuations, zippers, iteratees, ...

Comment: thank you - I of course know LYAH and love it (ok - there should be some exercises in there) - but the site is really helpful - thank you!